# Comparing two String arrays storing integer values separated by "#"

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, int

I have to compare two String arrays with integer values separated by "#" input by the user as follows:
Input 1: Size of the array:

```
             3
```

Input 2: (Array 1)

```
           1#4#5
           3#6#7 
           5#8#9
```

Input 2: (Array 2)

```
           1#3#5 
           4#6#7 
           5#7#9
```

They contain the same no. of integer strings per line as specified by the user input array size. For eg: the 1st line of Array 1 = `1#4#5` = 3 integer strings. 
In case, the array inputs are blank in any line, the output should be "invalid".

The output should be "yes" if the integer values in both the arrays are same irrespective of their position in the array i.e. if they are equivalent, otherwise the output should be "no".
My code passes very few test cases and mostly gives the correct output only when the two arrays are transpose of each other (when seen from the input format). It does not give the correct output when all the integer strings in both the arrays are same irrespective of their positions in the array.

eg. 1: Test case passed:

The output for the arrays in the example above is `yes`

eg.2: Test case failed:

Input 1: Size of the array:

```
             2
```

Input 2: (Array 1)

```
           1#6
           3#4
```

Input 2: (Array 2)

```
           6#3 
           4#1
```

Output: `no`

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringComparison
{
   public static void main (String[]args)
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  // Input the array size
  System.out.println("Enter the array size:");
  int size = input.nextInt();
  input.nextLine();
  String[] s1 = new String[size];
  String[] s2 = new String[size];

  // Input 1st array elements
  System.out.println("Enter the 1st array elements:");
  for (int i=0;i<size; i++)
  {
    s1[i]= input.nextLine();
  }
  // Input 2nd array elements
  System.out.println("Enter the 2nd array elements:");
   for (int i=0;i<size; i++)
  {
    s2[i]= input.nextLine();
  }
   // Check for equivalence
  System.out.println(equivalent (size, s1, s2));

}

  public static String equivalent (int input1, String[]input2, String[]input3)
  {
    String result =null;
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    char []b1 = new char[input1*input1];
    char[]b2 = new char[input1*input1];
    int[] num1 = new int[input1*input1];
    int[] num2 = new int[input1*input1];
   for (int i=0; i<input1;i++)
   {
     String[] a1 = input2[i].split("#");
     // if the user inputs are less or more than required
     try 
     {
       for (int j=0;j<input1;j++)
      sb1.append (a1[j]);
     }
     catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
     {
      result ="invalid";
      return result;
     }
     }

   for (int i=0; i<input1;i++)
   {
     String[] a2 = input3[i].split("#");
     // if the user inputs are less or more than required
    try 
     {
       for (int k=0;k<input1;k++)
      sb2.append (a2[k]);
     }
     catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
     {
      result ="invalid";
      return result;
     }
     }

  // Storing the contents of the StringBuilder objects in a char array
   sb1.getChars (0,((input1*input1)-1),b1,0);
   sb2.getChars (0,((input1*input1)-1),b2,0);

   // Converting the elements of the char array into integers and storing it in an int array
   for (int p=0; p<((input1*input1)-1);p++)
   {
     num1[p] = Character.digit( b1[p],(input1*input1)-1); 
   }
    // Converting the elements of the char array into integers and storing it in an int array
   for (int q=0; q<((input1*input1)-1);q++)
   {
     num2[q] = Character.digit( b2[q],(input1*input1)-1); 
   }
   // Sorting the two integer arrays
    Arrays.sort (num1);
    Arrays.sort (num2);

   if (Arrays.equals (num1,num2))
   {
     result = "yes"; 
   }
    else
   {
    result ="no";
   }
    return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: why not make it a 2-dimensional array? would be much easier to compare then

Comment: I don't how to implement a 2-dimensional array for Strings in this case since it might not meet the user input format.

Comment: does the user input has to have that format?

Comment: Yes. It has to be that format.

Comment: _I don't how to implement a 2-dimensional array for Strings_ just `String[][] name = new String[value][value];`

Comment: why 2nd case fails? `1#6\n3#4` and `6#3\n4#1` seems to match _The output should be "yes" if the integer values in both the arrays are same irrespective of their position in the array_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have rewritten your equivalent method. i hope its okay to use ArrayList.

```
private static String equivalent(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> num1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> num2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String str : s1) {
        String[] storage = str.split("#");
        for (String st : storage) {
            num1.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(st)));
        }
    }
    for (String str : s2) {
        String[] storage = str.split("#");
        for (String st : storage) {
            num2.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(st)));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(num1);
    Collections.sort(num2);
    if (num1.equals(num2)) {
        return "yes";
    } else {
        return "no";
    }

}
```

this does what you want to achieve with fewer code. if you need help understand or have any other questions feel free to ask

Comment: Array List and Collections Framework are really useful here. I think I need  really good practice to get used to them.

Comment: ArrayList is good if you want a simple add/remove and collections is just the same as Arrays for sorting

Comment: Your code is really good and the logic is superb. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you are using to make the integer array is wrong and it produced invalid entries.Try printing the array values.All the test cases will fail.

Try below to convert the the char into the integer

```
num2[q] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b2[q]));
num1[p] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b1[p]));
```

Note:Example 1 should have been "NO". There is no 8 in the second input.

Comment: You are right. The logic I used was incorrect. The whole idea of appending the elements of the string array after split into a StringBuilder object and then copying it in a char array wasn't useful and yes, the 1st example was a failed test case as well.